# WPFToolkit MessageBox's buttons are only in English

Tags: wpf, messagebox, wpftoolkit

I have a product works for multiple langueages. We use Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox, while we translate its content using resx files to other langueages.

The thing is that the buttons (Yes, No Cancel) which are given from the Message-Box type should be in Foreign langueages as well.. And they appear in English.

I assume there's a way to use a WPFToolkit dll that has given resources. Is there a way? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly which framework you are using, nor which button fails to translate but assuming you are using the Extended WPF Toolkit and according to their [documentation](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessageBox&referringTitle=Home#buttons) you should be able to translate what you want using the XXXButtonContent (for example YesButtonContent).

Comment: I need something even more simple. Can I use WPFToolkitExtended resources (Existing one.. with ready translations to Yes, No, Cancel)?